# Not able to use if condtion in handlebars

Tags: javascript, html, json, node.js, handlebars.js

if condition is always running and showing the first value. It is not going to else condition.

```
<tbody id="datatableBody">
                {{#Myfriends}}
                <tr class="trcss" id="iRows">
                    <td class="tdcss" id="tr_0" >{{Record.Name}}</td>
                    <td class="tdcss" id="tr_1"><div style="cursor:pointer; color:blue; text-decoration:underline;" onclick="getValue('{{FirstName}}','{{LastNAme}}','{{SStatus}}'">View <br> Details</div></td>
                    <td class="tdcss" id="tr_3">{{Record.FightSettlement}}</td>
                    <td class="tdcss" id="tr_4">{{Record.FightSettlementStatus}}</td>
                    <td class="tdcss" id="tr_5">{{Record.Reason}}</td>                       


                    {{#if "Record.FightSettlementStatus == 'FAILED'"}}
                        <td class="thcss" id="tr_8"><div style="cursor:pointer; color:blue; text-decoration:underline;" onclick="reSettle('{{Record.Solved}}');">Resettle</div></td>
                    {{else}}
                        <td class="thcss" id="tr_8">No Action Required</td>
                    {{/if}}                                
                </tr>
                {{/Myfriends}}
            </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handlebars will not evaluate your expression.  You will need to evaluate it yourself and set a boolean variable or use something like the #xIf helper.